# Midterm asks I produce a count for 'country' and a count for 'contact title' from XML doc

Tags: javascript, xml

I created a table that populates the data from XML file. But I am having trouble "creating a count".
I just want to count the Countries and Job Titles, there are a lot of repeating ones. I think the Prof. wants us to List something like:

Germany: 4 Count

Mexico: 5 Count

***Fragment of XML doc:***

```
<dataroot>
<forMid>
<cust>ALFKI</cust>
<abc>Maria Anders</abc>
<contacttitle>Sales Representative</contacttitle>
<city>Berlin</city>
<country>Germany</country>
</forMid>
<forMid>
<cust>ANATR</cust>
<abc>Ana Trujillo</abc>
<contacttitle>Owner</contacttitle>
<city>México D.F.</city>
<country>Mexico</country>
</forMid>
<forMid>
<cust>ANTON</cust>
<abc>Antonio Moreno</abc>
<contacttitle>Owner</contacttitle>
<city>México D.F.</city>
<country>Mexico</country>
</forMid>
</dataroot>
```

***Here is what my table script looks like if if helps:***

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        imAnnoyed(this);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "midA.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
  function imAnnoyed(xml) {
    var i;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    const mad = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("forMid");
    var table = "<col><col><col><col><col><tr><th>Business ID</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Title</th><th>City</th><th>Country</th></tr>";
    for (i = 0; i < mad.length; i++) {
      table += "<tr><td>" +
      mad[i].getElementsByTagName("cust")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      mad[i].getElementsByTagName("abc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      mad[i].getElementsByTagName("contacttitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      mad[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" +
      mad[i].getElementsByTagName("country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not use ajax, use fetch (built into js)

1. Get all the tags with tagname you want
2. Get innerHTML/content of tag.
3. Create hashmap. key will be country country.
4. Set count to 1 if new item, if already exist increment by one.
5. Get the count by looping through the hash.

```js
function loadDoc() {
  // use fetch to load xml file
  fetch("midA.xml")
    // convert response to text
    .then((resp) => resp.text())
    // parse text to xml
    .then((xml) => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"))
    // call your function imAnnoyed
    .then(imAnnoyed)
    // catch errors
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

function imAnnoyed(xml) {
  // select all tags country
  let countryList = xml.querySelectorAll("country");
  // convert tag to innerHTML (text)
  countryList = Array.from(countryList).map((tag) => tag.innerHTML);
  // create hashmap
  const hash = new Map();
  //
  countryList.forEach((country) =>
    // if country is in hashmap increment value by 1
    // else add it and set value to 1
    hash.has(country)
      ? hash.set(country, hash.get(country) + 1)
      : hash.set(country, 1)
  );
  // convert to array
  items = Array.from(hash.entries());
  // loop through final result
  items.forEach(([country, count]) => {
    // print values or add your logic below
    console.log(country, count);
  });
}

// Output:
// Germany 1
// Mexico 2
```

Comment: Thank you! I would, unfortunately this is an ajax class lol and not the most helpful prof.

Comment: @wavedbabe Then you can use your `loadDoc()` function and call `imAnnoyed(this.responseXML);` instead of `imAnnoyed(this);` and do your additional table displaying at the end.

Comment: @wavedbabe check these resources for learning programming, https://www.youtube.com/c/Freecodecamp, https://www.youtube.com/c/Fireship, https://www.youtube.com/c/WebDevSimplified
Professors are not going to help, especially in programming, we are supposed to learn ourselves.